# Why does fasd sometimes forget some files/directories?

Tags: shell, zsh, fasd

Sometimes my fasd forgets a file or a directory.
I thought it was because of a maximum size of the "~/.fasd" file but i realized it wasn't, because I cleaned it and noticed it forgets items also when has a low number of lines.
So... does it automatically forget folders/files when their score is too low or are there other ways it forgets items?
Thanks in advance.